# Vaadin Anchor: Preventing opening a link

Tags: vaadin-flow

I am trying to use vaadin anchor to open a new dialog not to open a new link. But even though I removed the href, it navigates to opening screen. How can I prevent that?

https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/upgrading/essential-steps
I followed these steps, but it does not work.

Anchor logoutLink = new Anchor("/logout", "Logout from app");
logoutLink.getElement().setAttribute("router-ignore", true);

Comment: Dialog? Vaadin component dialog like  com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog or something else? 

BTW. In your code snippet above you are giving the href in the constructor.

It looks like you are trying to implement login. Maybe that should be done somehow else than with navigation with an Anchor.